# C# PropertyGrid - How to make array elements read only?

Tags: c#, readonly, propertygrid

I have a PropertyGrid to which I add a array of bool-values. The array itself is marked as ReadOnly, which is recognized properly by the property grid.

BUT: If I expand the array in the Grid, all the items are editable by the user. Of course that's not what I want. If the array itself is marked a s ReadOnly all its elements shall be as well!

Is there any way to achieve this behavior in the PropertyGrid?

Comment: If your binding the collection to the propertygrid, then you can have that collection indexers set property private. That way none can set.

Comment: What do you mean, your array is read-only? Are you wrapping it using ReadOnlyCollection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx). Using a TypeConverter, you can control the properties that the PropertyGrid shows, and their behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The readonly keyword doesn't work the way you think it does:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static readonly bool[] arr = { false, true };

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        arr[0] = true;
    }
}
```

Yes, use TypeConverter to alter the behavior of types in PropertyGrid.  Or just give it the [Browsable(false)] attribute because nobody wants to look at an array of booleans anyway.